# Cut,Concat and Convert on python ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I want to use the command line code below in python. It first cut parts from a video, then combine them. After that it changes the video format .ts to .mp4. How can I use it in python code?

Command Line Code:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts  \
-ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:20 \
-c:v copy -c:a copy Files/intro.ts && ffmpeg -i input.ts  \
-ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:20 \
-c:v copy -c:a copy Files/first.ts && ffmpeg -i input.ts \
-ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:20 \
-c:v copy -c:a copy Files/second.ts && ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i Files/mylist.txt -c copy output.ts \
&& ffmpeg -i output.ts -c copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

u could try use python to run cmd command.

```py
import os

command = """ffmpeg -i input.ts  \
-ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:20 \
-c:v copy -c:a copy Files/intro.ts && ffmpeg -i input.ts  \
-ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:20 \
-c:v copy -c:a copy Files/first.ts && ffmpeg -i input.ts \
-ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:20 \
-c:v copy -c:a copy Files/second.ts && ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i Files/mylist.txt -c copy output.ts \
&& ffmpeg -i output.ts -c copy output.mp4"""
os.system(command)
```